# Range.Replace, used in cells content

Tags: vba, replace

Want to substitute the content in a cell, in replacement of the content in another cell:

```
Selection.Replace What:= *content of the G7 cell, Replacement:= Content of the H7 cell, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

What can I do for the variant "what" in `Range.Replace` understand that he must take a content in one cell defined in some `Range("G7")`, and variant Replacement, do the same for other `range("H7")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Range("G7").Value` like:

```
Selection.Replace What:=Range("G7").Value, Replacement:=Range("H7").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```